# Use image path stored in database to display the image in Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel

In my ImageController, I've moved an image to a directory and saved the image path in a table in database as,

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $new_country = new SelectCountry();
    $message = [
        'required' => "This field can not be empty",
    ];

    $this->validate($request, [
        'country_name' => 'required',
        'alternate_title' => 'required',
        'country_flag' => 'required',
    ], $message);


    $new_country->country_name = $request->country_name;
    $new_country->alternate_title = $request->alternate_title;
    if($request->hasfile('country_flag'))
    {
        $country_flag_image = $request->file('country_flag');

        $country_flag_name = $country_flag_image->getClientOriginalName();

        $extention = $country_flag_image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $dirpath = public_path('assets/images/country/');
        $country_flag_image->move($dirpath,$country_flag_name);

        $new_country->country_flag_path = $dirpath.$country_flag_name;
    }
    $new_country->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.country');
}
```

Now I want to use the path and display the image along other informations. I've used the following code to return view,

```php
public function select_country() 
{
    $countries = SelectCountry::all();
    return view('auth.select_country')->with('countries',$countries);
}
```

And in the view, I've used following code to display datas stored in the database,

```php
<table class="table-hover table-responsive container-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12">        
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country Name</th>
            <th>Alternate Title</th>
            <th>Country Flag</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
          <td>{{ $country->country_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $country->alternate_title }}</td>
          <td><img src="{{ $country->country_flag_path }}"></td>
          <td>
            <a type="button" href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Update</a>
            <a type="button" href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
          </td>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

The problem is the image is not displayed while other informations are displayed. The *src* attribute in *img* tag is returning path but not directory.

If there is any solution, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `dd($country);` function to see what information is being passed to the view?

Comment: Yes I did. It returns country_name and alternate_title but not the image. Instead of image, it returns whole directory path as:
"country_flag_path" => "C:\Users\Ashok\Desktop\Laravel\LaravelConsultancy\public/assets/images/country/canada.png"

Comment: I *think* `public_path('assets/images/country/');` is your issue. Try setting it to just `$dirpath = "images/country"` as Laravel looks inside `public` by default. You can then reference it by doing `src="{{ asset($country->country_flag_path) }}`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi there, as the solution has worked for you please can you click the tick next to my answer to mark it as accepted? Thank you :)

Comment: Instead of editing my answer, which is clearly helping you, can you please accept it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue lies with where you are setting the storage folder. Laravel with automatically reference the `public` folder for storage of images etc so there's no need for the `public_path` function.

Try setting your `$dirpath` to just `$dirpath = "/asset/images/country"` as Laravel looks inside `public` by default. You can then reference it by doing `<img src="{{ $country->country_flag_path }}">`

Then upload a new image and see what the database has the path set to, hopefully it should be a bit more normal :)

Please note that my original answer of:

Try setting your `$dirpath` to just `$dirpath = "images/country"` as Laravel looks inside `public` by default. You can then reference it by doing `<img src="{{ asset($country->country_flag_path) }}">`

Should still work as it's how I've always done it :)